# Is There A Way To Add Products That Are Only Available In Backend?

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, products, backend

I need to add some products to my site that are only allowed to be ordered by the Sales staff. Therefore, I need them not to show on the website, but they need to still be able to available via a MOTO order in the backend.

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290769/magento-restrict-some-catogories-for-some-customer-groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only 2 ways to do this (without extensive programming) is

1) to create a separate website that is not reachable / available on the frontend. You can add the products to that website

2) set to products to catalog only visibility but don't add them to any category.
You will be able to find them via the order create product grid but not in the frontend.

Option 2 is probably the easiest with the added benefit of having all the standard settings of the website you're creating the order under.

Comment: Of course - no categories! What an idiot I am!!! Thank you, sorry for being so thick!!

Comment: Haha no worries. I've had a similar case a while back so didn't need to think about the answer :)